# Having Trouble with CountryData [EDITED]

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I have a list which I call by

```
countryExportPartners = 
 Table[l = CountryData[][[n]]; {l, 
 CountryData[l, "ExportPartners"]}, {n, 1, Length[CountryData[]]}]
```

I have another piece of code which I find the position of a country within this list

```
findPosition[name_String] := 
 Flatten[Position[
   countryExportPartners, {Entity["Country", name], _}]]
```

It works with countries such as India and China, but if I try to do USA the function fails to return anything. Is there something I did wrong here? Thanks for the help.

An Example of the Code:

```
In[23]:= findPosition[name_String] := 
Flatten[Position[countryExportPartners, {Entity["Country", name], 
_}]]
findPosition["USA"]
findPosition["China"]
countryExportPartners[[36]]

Out[24]= {}

Out[25]= {36}

Out[26]= {Entity["Country", 
 "China"], {Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
 Entity["Country", "HongKong"], Entity["Country", "Japan"], 
 Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"], Entity["Country", "Germany"]}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration of attempting to use the function for the USA?

Comment: You probably used “United States” instead of “UnitedStates”

Comment: Hi, I added an example of the code.

Comment: As I said before, use "UnitedStates", i.e. `findPosition["UnitedStates"]`

Comment: I tried UnitedStates, and it returned 3 values.